# How to escape percent sign in shell command

Tags: xetex, windows, shell-escape, git

I am working on a macro which will build revision history table in my document using Git tags.
Each published version of my document has a tag with short description.
I want to use them to automatically build revision table while compiling with XeLaTeX in Windows.

Using Git command below i get all information I need to create the revision history table.
Output is formatted in CSV-like format.

```sh
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short); %(taggerdate:short); %(subject); %(*authorname); %(*authoremail)' refs/tags
```

I modified a [macro for parsing CSV file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593752/95312) so that I can read the output of the Git command and build my revision history table (not formatted yet as table in the script).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\printrow}[5]{tag: #1 (#3) at #2 by #4 #5 + \\}

\begin{document}

\def\readrow #1;#2;#3;#4;#5;{\ifx^#5^\else 
   \printrow{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
   \expandafter\readrow\fi}
\def\startread {\readrow} % skip first row
\begingroup
   \endlinechar=`; \everyeof={;;;;;} \catcode`\@=11
   \expandafter \startread \@@input |"git revhist" %
\endgroup % 

\end{document}
```

It works with pre-saved output of the command, but when I paste the full command string into `\@@input` and try to compile (`xelatex -shell-escape .\read-git-history-test.tex`), XeLaTeX complains:

```
{|"git for-each-ref --format='
! Paragraph ended before \@iinput was complete.
<to be read again>
                   \par
```

I did a workaround by defining Git alias (`git revhist` -see below) but if one of my colleagues will try to compile it without defining the alias, it will fail. No, they do not read REDAME's...

```
git config --global alias.revhist "for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short); %(taggerdate:short); %(subject); %(*authorname); %(*authoremail);' refs/tags"
```

Is it possible to call the full Git command in `*.tex` file not to corrupt it by the `%` signs?

Comment: By the way you may want to learn how catcode works in TeX properly by yourself first. Read TeX by topic or TeXbook

Comment: use `\@percentchar` or locally make `%` have catcode 12

Comment: They used to have write18, nowadays it's just input-pipe. [pdftex - \write18 pass % through to shell - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/write18-pass-through-to-shell) Mostly-same principle though. (both \input and \write x-expand the argument)

Comment: but I don't know what the \input|... is called (to search for it).

Comment: @user202729 "used to have write18" ? where has that been removed (other than luatex)?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As in "they used to have to *use* write18"

Comment: @user202729 yes I don't know who you mean by "they"

Comment: You can try to use [iexec](https://ctan.org/pkg/iexec) package, which does it all for you: escaping chars, checking exit code of the script, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `\@percentchar` as suggested by @DavidCarlisle, and it works as expected.

```tex
\def\readrow #1;#2;#3;#4;#5;{\ifx^#5^\else
   \addrevision{#1}{#2}{#4}{#3}%
   \expandafter\readrow\fi}
\def\startread {\readrow} % skip first row
\begingroup
   \endlinechar=`; \everyeof={;;;;;} \catcode`\@=11
   \expandafter \startread \@@input |"git for-each-ref --format='\@percentchar(refname:short); \@percentchar(taggerdate:short); \@percentchar(subject); \@percentchar(*authorname); \@percentchar(*authoremail)' refs/tags" %
\endgroup %
```